# subclipse move project from one repository to another

Tags: eclipse, subclipse

For example my current project is on `http://someserver/svn/proj_name1`.

How to move my project to `http://someserver/svn/proj_name2`(there created folders `tag, trunk, branches`)?

Comment: Copy - paste - rename.

Comment: Well it seems nothing special